# Constructors GetInfo

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and am working on classes and understanding them. My problem is I am not understanding how to create a `Get` to retrieve the private variable `_yourname` and `Set` to set the private variable `_yourname`.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class InputClass
    {
        private string _yourName;
        public string _banner;
        public virtual void GetInfo();
        public InputClass(String _banner)
        {
            _banner = "Enter your name";
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I am using the wrong function to `GetInfo`. But I am also wondering when I have the `GetInfo` if in the `()` I should write `_yourname` in it.

Comment: Have you read this page?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Use `this._banner` in the constructor otherwise you are just setting the local var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# there are properties, which have the function of public getter and setter methods in other languages:

```
    class InputClass
      {
        private string _yourName;
        public string _banner;

        public InputClass(String _banner)
        {
            this._banner = _banner;    
        }

        public string YourName 
        {
             get { return _yourName; }
             set { _yourName = value; }
        }

    }
```

But you can use auto properties, if you want:

```
    class InputClass
    {
       public InputClass(String _banner)
        {
            Banner = _banner;    
        }

        public string YourName 
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Banner 
        {
            get; set;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to provide access to the `_yourName` field.  If so then just use a property

```
class InputClass {

  public string YourName { 
    get { return _yourName; }
    set { _yourName = value; }
  }

  ...
}
```

Now consumers of `InputClass` can access it as if it were a read only field.

```
InputClass ic = ...;
string yourName = ic.YourName;
ic.YourName = "hello";
```

Note: C# provides a special syntax for simple properties like this which are just meant to be wrappers over private fields.  It's named auto-implemented properties

```
class InputClass { 
  public string YourName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override getters and settings using the `get` and `set` keywords.  For example:

```
class InputClass
{
    private string _yourName;
    private string _banner;

    public YourName
    {
       get { return _yourName; }
       set { _yourName = value; }
    }

    public Banner
    {
       get { return _banner; }
       set { _banner = value; }
    }

    public InputClass(String banner)
    {
       _banner = banner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use properties instead of members, you get a free accessor (get) and mutator (set).

```
    public string YourName { get; set; }
    public string Banner { get; set; }
```

2.) You can take advantage of the default constructor, and declare it on the fly.

```
        //the old way:
        InputClass myClass = new InputClass();
        myClass.YourName = "Bob";
        myClass.Banner = "Test Banner";

        //on the fly:
        InputClass myClass = new InputClass()
        {
            YourName = "Bob",
            Banner = "Test Banner"
        }
```